# SASS CSS: string interpolation ouputs unexpected value

Tags: css, sass

I've tried following variations:

```
font-family: "Dosis" , Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;

font-family: "'Dosis'", + Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;

font-family: "Dosis", + Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
```

What I want:

```
font-family: 'Dosis',  Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
```

And what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Is `Dosis` supposed to be a variable?

Comment: @QuentinVeron
Yes, I have also tried
`$dosis: " 'Dosis',  Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif  ";
font-family : $dosis; `

Answer (score 1):

You don't need interpolation.

```
$dosis: 'Dosis';

.foo {
  font-family: $dosis, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
}
```

Or if you want the whole font stack as variable:

```
$font-stack: 'Dosis', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;

.foo {
  font-family: $font-stack;
}
```